# Cómo crear una lista con diferentes partes de un dataframe utilizando un condicional?

Tags: r, lista, condiciones

Si tengo un dataframe R, de 4 columnas

```
R:
X       Y       Z       L
            .
            .
            .
a       2       8       0
b       3       2       0
c       12      5       0 
d       3       22      0
e       4       33      0
f       2       1       1
g       3       4       0
h       1       2       0
i       2       5       0 
j       7       4       0
k       3       3       1
...
```

Si N es el numero de veces que L > 0, como crear una lista de N objetos los cuales esten conformados de la siguiente manera:

Si i es la fila donde L>0 crear un objeto que contenga las filas entre i-3 e i del dataframe R: es decir:

```
list()
[1]
    d       3       22      0
    e       4       33      0
    f       2       1       1
[2]
    i       2       5       0 
    j       7       4       0
    k       3       3       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar esto:

```
df<-data.frame(X=letters, Y=rnorm(26,0,1),L=rbinom(26,1,0.5))
df


List<-list()
for (i in 3:length(df$X)) {
  if (df$L[i] == 1) {
    a <- df[(i-2):i,]
  } else { a<-NULL 
    }

  List[[length(List)+1]] = a

}


List
```

Answer (score 0):

Podemos aprovechar a **R** haciendo uso de funciones vectorizadas, que hacen el código simple y performante, por ejemplo:

```
split(df, cumsum(c(df$x[1],df$x[-nrow(df)])))
```

Explicación:

- [`split()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html) puede "desarmar" un `data.frame` en grupos y devolverlos separados en una lista. Para desagruparlos, es necesario armar un vector de igual longitud del objeto a desagrupar, pero con algún dato que determine cada grupo, por ejemplo, un vector: `c(0,0,0,1,1,2)` nos permitirá dividir el `data.frame` en tres grupos de 3, 2 y 1 ítem cada uno.
- Para armar los grupos usamos [`cumsum()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cumsum.html) que va generando la suma acumulada, pero con un pequeño truco, desplazamos todos los valores un elemento hacía adelante, para que cuando aparezca un `1` el cual va a modificar la suma acumulada, el cambio aplique al siguiente grupo y no al actual. la idea es si el vector es este vector: `c(0,0,1,0,1,0)`, terminar con un vector como este:  `c(0,0,0,1,1,2)`, con esto ya podremos aplicar el [`split()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html) tal como buscamos

El ejemplo completo sería este:

```
set.seed(200)
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100),
                 x = sample(c(1,0), 100, prob=c(0.3,0.7),replace=TRUE)
)

split(df, cumsum(c(df$x[1],df$x[-nrow(df)])))
```